# How to index CommentsField in Haystack?

Tags: django-haystack

I have a `comments = CommentsField()` in my Django model. I am wondering how can I index this CommentsField() type in Haystack as `indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do,

```
comment = indexes.CharField(model_attr='comments')
```

And prepare comment field above as,

```
prepare_comment(self,obj):
    return obj.comment
```

obj.comment is the actual content of the comment

Refer link below for more on prepare 
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchfield_api.html?highlight=prepare#SearchField.prepare